# How to rbind() only the columns with similar yet different names of two different datasets?

Tags: r

I have two datasets of different column dimensions, let's say:

```
df1<-data.frame(How.are.you.today=c(1,1,1), How.were.you.yesterday=c(2,2,2), How.old.are.you=c(3,3,3))

df2<-data.frame(Would.you.mind.telling.us.How.are.you.today=c(1,1,1), Could.you.tell.us.How.were.you.yesterday=c(2,2,2))
```

I want to use

```
plyr::rbind.fill (df1, df2)
```

to merge the rows of those two datasets, but I want somehow to detect and match the similar ones. In this case all the colunms of df1. Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this as:

```
a <- which(!adist(names(df1),names(df2),partial = TRUE),T)
plyr::rbind.fill(df1,setNames(df2, replace(names(df2), a[, 2], names(df1)[a[,1]])))
  How.are.you.today How.were.you.yesterday How.old.are.you
1                 1                      2               3
2                 1                      2               3
3                 1                      2               3
4                 1                      2              NA
5                 1                      2              NA
6                 1                      2              NA
```

Comment: Thanks Onyambu, indeed it works perfectly for my example! Now I'm trying to adjust for a real life problem where it seems to do the job though it does not detect some matches, for example in cases that the string is quite long and the partiality quite significant. If you know any way to adjust the minimum distance please share! I will be looking into this too. Thanks again!

Comment: @Yach in that case you will use `Vectorize(agrep)(names(df1),list(names(df2))`  and you can control the `max.distance` argument within `agrep` hence be able to accomplish what you want

Comment: Thanks for your help but I really can't find a way to use your suggestion I'm neither familiar with ```Vectorize``` nor ```agrep``` thus I really feel lost here.